# SASS - error parsing associative array

Tags: css, compiler-errors, sass, associative-array, compass-sass

I have a SASS file _button-map-mixin.css that starts with the following associative array:

```
$cache: (
    color: (),
    font-size: (),
    line-height: (),
    background-color: (),
    font-family: ()
);
```

When I compile the file, I get the following error:

> Invalid CSS after " color": expected ")", was ": (),"

I don't understand - isn't this valid syntax?

It almost seems like the compiler doesn't recognize an associative array - but I'm using SASS version 3.3.6 (and Compass 0.12.6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sass 3.3.7 and compass 1.0 (it's in alpha `gem install compass --pre`) If you got wdm related error then also install wdm(require "Ruby Development Kit") gem. If you keep your gem list clean it will be easier to catch dependency errors. Run `gem list --local` and uninstall all previous versions of compass and sass if you don't need them.

Comment: Thanks! But NOTE: I got an error "LoadError on line ["45"] of C: cannot load such file -- wdm", so I needed to install wdm ("gem install wdm"), but in order to install that, I first had to install the Ruby Development Kit (http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/).