# Installing Compass on windows, but having already installed SASS gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sass, compass-sass

I am new to Ruby and Gems and like its simplicity. I have a question regarding different versions same gems installed. I wanted to use SASS and Compass so I used the following steps.

1. Installed Ruby on my Windows 7 Os
2. Installed SASS using command line "gem install sass". This installed Sass-3.3.7 by default.
3. Installed Compass using command line "gem install compass". This installed 4 Gems and one of them is sass-3.2.19.

When I looked into the **ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems** folder, I can see there are two different versions of SASS. Is that alright to have two versions of same gem (SASS) on same machine. Or is it a better approach to have only one version of SASS installed. In the later case how do I customize the Compass gem install to avoid SASS installation and point to an existing SASS installation.

I am just new and experimenting with this stuff and so install/uninstall is not any issue for me now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23709780/ruby-sass-unable-to-resolve-dependancies

Comment: I prefer both versions installed. That way I would be able to use standalone SASS version independently of versions required by Compass.

Comment: Ok?  That's allowed.  Compass will use the newest version of Sass that it is compatible with.

Comment: Yes, I understand that now. Just letting you know, your link resolved my doubt.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use compass 1.0.alpha `gem install compass --pre`  because previous versions can't work with the last versions of the sass. Also it's a good idea to run `gem list --local` and uninstall older versions of sass and compass because some gems can pool old version and you will have weird errors like this one: [SASS - error parsing associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668366/sass-error-parsing-associative-array/23675341#23675341)

Comment: Having an old version of Sass laying around has nothing to do with the problem you're referencing.

Comment: @cimmanon i had similar issues with the different sass frameworks and i often catch them with `gem list --local` looking for different versions and dependencies. And this way nothing will fall back on older version that i installed ages ago. it's important since testing for interoperability of all possible gem version combinations is almost impossible.